# ssh-copy-id closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to copy public ssh with ssh-copy-id but it gives a connection close:

```
user@serverA:~/ctm/cm/AFT/data/Keys$ ssh-copy-id -p 1222 -i /home/user/keys/serverA.pub  vivek@serverB
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/user/keys/serverA.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Password authentication
Password:
Connection to serverB closed by remote host.
```

With ssh:

```
user@serverA:~/ctm/cm/AFT/data$ ssh -vvv -p 1222 vivek@serverB
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "serverB" port 1222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to serverB [192.168.1.121] port 1222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version APACHE-SSHD-2.2.0
debug1: no match: APACHE-SSHD-2.2.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to serverB:1222 as 'vivek'
debug3: put_host_port: [serverB]:1222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [serverB]:1222
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:G9DKL3IqHJntw6UXxRDAwRHv//ChH8K49rEKK/DgzuQ
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.121]:1222
debug3: put_host_port: [serverB]:1222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [serverB]:1222
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.121]:1222
debug1: Host '[serverB]:1222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55c9d1aa29b0)
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,keyboard-interactive,publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
Password authentication
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Any help please?

Comment: Try running `ssh` with `-v`, `-vv`, and `-vvv` to increase verbosity. Kindly add the detailed output.

Comment: It's not clear whether the connection closes _before_ you have the opportunity to enter the password, or if it closes after.

Comment: @FelixJN  I've edited main post with ssh output verbose

Comment: @Kusalananda I've edited main post with ssh output verbose

Comment: Can you login with password?

Comment: To access the machine to deposit your public SSH key, you need to enter your login password on that machine. After depositing your key on the remote machine, you no longer have to enter the login password (but you may still have to enter the key's password if you have a password set on the key). If you don't have access to the remote machine, you must get an administrator to add the public key for you.

Comment: It's still not clear what the actual issue is, though. Could you update the question, explicitly saying what it is that isn't working the way you expect it to?

Comment: Thanks, I achive the solution. I need the user in authorized_keys of the destination like : vivek ssh-rasa xxxxxxx . If I don't add username dont works. I thouht that I only need to add user in source, not in destination

Comment: @defekas17 That makes no sense. A line in the `authorized_keys` file can't start with a username (see [the `sshd` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT)). Also, an `authorized_keys` file does nothing on the computer you're connecting _from_.